# Django url template with a filter

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm getting url reverse errors and think this line is to blame.

```
{% if has_change_permission %}
    <a href="{% url 'opts|admin_urlname:changelist' %}">
    {{ opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}</a>
{% else %}{
    { opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}
{% endif %}
```

Am I corect in placing the entire filter within single quotes or do I need a double quote around the changelist argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have any quotes since you're referencing a context variable and not providing a string value. The argument is still a string though so the correct line is `<a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'changelist' %}">`.